# Reset password function with bcrypt does not work, Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

So i made a reset password function and it looks like this:

```
router.get('/reset/:id',function(req,res,next){
    User.findOne({'resetToken': req.params.id.trim()})
        .exec(function(error, user){
            if (error) return next(error);
            else if(!user){
                var err = new Error('Invalid Reset Link! The system is unable to find a user with the given reset code.');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            }else return res.render('resetpass',{token: req.params.id});
        })
})

router.post('/reset/:id', function(req,res,next){
    if(req.body.newPassword === req.body.confirmNewPassword)
    User.findOne({'resetToken': req.params.id.trim()},function(error,user){
        if(error) return next(error);
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 5, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            user.password = hash;
            user.resetToken ='';
            user.save(); 
        })

    });
    return res.redirect('/login');          
})
```

so when i complete the reset password fields and click submit i get this in console : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

and if i use this:

```
  router.post('/reset/:id', function(req,res,next){
    if(req.body.newPassword === req.body.confirmNewPassword)
    var cp;
    User.findOne({'resetToken': req.params.id.trim()},function(error,user){
        if(error) return next(error);
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 5, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            cp = hash;
        })
        user.password = cp;
        user.resetToken ='';
        user.save(); 
    });
    return res.redirect('/login');          
})
```

my user.password is empty and i get this : Cannot set property 'password' of null -> becouse i set that in UserSchema.
So why is that ?  i tried with console.logs in other function just with variables and is something like that :

```
bcrypt.hash(.... {console.log('a') }) 
console.log('b');
```

my console looks like this :

```
b
a
```

So bcrypt console.log is after. What can i do ?

Comment: nvm i solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `User.findOne()` is an async operation.

The redirection `res.redirect('/login')` should be called **after** new password is saved.

You could try this code below:

```
router.post('/reset/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.newPassword === req.body.confirmNewPassword) {
        User.findOne({
            'resetToken': req.params.id.trim()
        }, function (error, user) {
            if (error) return next(error);
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 5, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                user.resetToken = '';
                user.save();

                // Do the redirection here
                res.redirect('/login');
            })

        });
    }

    // Do nothing here
})
```